# Class sees array.lengh but no it's data

Tags: android, class, variables, baseadapter

I have a strange error in my code and i can't see the problem. I have a main class where I have an other class inside. I have an arraylist declared in the main class and if I acces to it in somepart of the class i can have all the information but when i acces to it in the inner class it can't see the data. Why?

The inner class is an BaseAdapter for making a viewlist. I called it from oncreate bundle as:

```
public class Main extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {
//new adapter
private EfficientAdapter adap;
//The variable which makes the error
public static ArrayList<String> data2 = new ArrayList<String>();    
protected static Context mContext=null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.nuevoingr);

    data2.clear();
    data2.add("just adding 1");
    adap = new EfficientAdapter(this);
    setListAdapter(adap);
```

and the inner class is (the problem is at the end of it):

```
public static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Context context;

    public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
        // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    /**
     * Make a view to hold each row.
     *
     * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getView(int, android.view.View,
    *      android.view.ViewGroup)
    */
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid
        // unneccessary calls
        // to findViewById() on each row.
        ViewHolder holder;

        // When convertView is not null, we can reuse it directly, there is
        // no need
        // to reinflate it. We only inflate a new View when the convertView
        // supplied
        // by ListView is null.
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.pruebas, null);

            // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children
            // views
            // we want to bind data to.
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textLine = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pr2);
            holder.buttonLine = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pr1);


            convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                private int pos = position;

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Click-" + String.valueOf(pos), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
                }
            });

            holder.buttonLine.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                private int pos = position;

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Delete-" + String.valueOf(pos), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     
                }
            });
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
            // and the ImageView.
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // Bind the data efficiently with the holder.
        holder.textLine.setText(String.valueOf(position));

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView textLine;
        ImageButton buttonLine;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }


//Here it comes the problem. Before editing my program this code was provide to include     only a few values from 
a String array declared at the same moment of data2 called data. What I do now is to     declare an arraylist so
 I can include more values and then I refresh the adaptor and here I pass the arraylist     to an array to be equal as
 it was before.
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String [] change = (String[]) data2.toArray(new String[data2.size()]);  
        return change.length;
        //return data.length;
    }
//Same problem   
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String [] change = (String[]) data2.toArray(new String[data2.size()]);
        return change[position];
        //return data[position];
    }

}
```

What is strange is that this baseAdapter is for a listview and when it updates it's data there's as rows as arraylist.length but its data it's not include it and all rows are detected as the same when clicking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. 
I changed the code to this one: [techdroid.kbeanie.com/2009/07/custom-listview-for-android.html](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2009/07/custom-listview-for-android.html)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    if(Main.data2!=null)
    {
        return Main.data2.size();
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    if(Main.data2!=null)
    {
        return Main.data2.get(position);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: really strange. i think there's something wrong from where u are calling getCount() method. Debug by putting a breakpoint in getCount() method or by putting a log message.

Comment: I've put a breakpoint at if(Main.data2!=null)(getcount), return 0 and return Main.data2.size();. When the app starts ther are like 8 calls to getcount and eclipse stops me the 8 times in both arguments, return Main.data2.size(); and return 0 but I can see that data2 has its information. I just can't understand anything. Maybe I should use another code just for been able to make a listview with a button that handles both text and button click. Do you know some page where i can find an alternative way? Thanks